Getting "OSError: Project was not passed and could not be determined from the environment" when running gcloud beta code dev
I have a Flask app that runs fine in Cloud run, but when I try to test it locally using gcloud beta code dev --application-default-credential I get the following error:
- deployment/snapshotter: container snapshotter-container terminated with exit code 3
    - pod/snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd: container snapshotter-container terminated with exit code 3
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container] [2024-12-29 04:46:31 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container] [2024-12-29 04:46:31 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container] [2024-12-29 04:46:31 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container] [2024-12-29 04:46:31 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container] [2024-12-29 04:46:32 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container] Traceback (most recent call last):
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]     worker.init_process()
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]     self.load_wsgi()
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]     self.callable = self.load()
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]     return self.load_wsgiapp()
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "/app/main.py", line 5, in <module>
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]     from snapshotter import Snapshotter
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "/app/snapshotter.py", line 15, in <module>
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]     from logger import get_logger
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "/app/logger.py", line 6, in <module>
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]     log_client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/client.py", line 122, in __init__
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]     super(Client, self).__init__(
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/client/__init__.py", line 320, in __init__
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]     _ClientProjectMixin.__init__(self, project=project, credentials=credentials)
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/client/__init__.py", line 271, in __init__
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container]     raise EnvironmentError(
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container] OSError: Project was not passed and could not be determined from the environment.
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container] [2024-12-29 04:46:32 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container] [2024-12-29 04:46:32 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:7) exited with code 3
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container] [2024-12-29 04:46:32 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
      > [snapshotter-6b5684f658-9g7nd snapshotter-container] [2024-12-29 04:46:32 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
 - deployment/snapshotter failed. Error: container snapshotter-container terminated with exit code 3.

Since gcloud beta code dev is supposed to emulate a Cloud Run service in a local development environment, I was assuming this would just work because it runs in Cloud run with no errors. In this case I'm instantiating a cloud logging client with log_client = google.cloud.logging.Client() and if I run this on my machine (MacOS) I get no errors. I have set the default project on my machine with gcloud config set project.

Your debugging is good.
I think (!?) the explanation of the observed behavior is that gcloud beta code dev uses Docker and runs a minikube container. This isolates this runtime environment from your host's gcloud installation|config.
I assume (!?) --application-default-credential flag exposes your host's (on Linux ${HOME}/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json which doesn't specify a Project.
When you run this locally, with gcloud config set project, Application Default Credentials finds the Project. If you were to gcloud project unset project, I think you'd observe the same behavior.
If you were to use a Service Account (instead of user credentials), I assume this would work because Service Accounts *do specify a Project.
It's surprising to me that gcloud beta code dev doesn't appear (!?) to include a mechanism to specify the Project (--project doesn't work) and so I assume there is a way to do this (I just don't know it [see below]).
So, you've two imperfect solutions:

Force the Cloud Logging client to use
a defined Project (google.cloud.logging.Client(project=project))
(Worse) os.environ["GCLOUD_PROJECT"] = project

Running minikube is an imperfect solution because (as you've experienced) it can add complexity.
When I'm debugging Cloud Run services, I prefer running the image directly on my host, mounting credentials and setting environment variables as needed.
